# How to bind Radio Buttons In Blazor?

Tags: c#, binding, radio-button, blazor

Radio button binding is not happening in blazor. As per the documentation it is suggested to use InputRadio tag but this tag doesn't work in blazor and shows binding issue. Any suggestions on how to bind a radio button

Answer (score 14):

The below code works for me

```
<input type="radio" checked="@(User.Gender == GenderEnum.Male)"
    name="Gender" @onchange="@(() => User.Gender = GenderEnum.Male)" />
<label>Male</label>

<input type="radio" checked="@(User.Gender == GenderEnum.Female)"
    name="Gender" @onchange="@(() => User.Gender = GenderEnum.Female)" />
<label>Female</label>

<input type="radio" checked="@(User.Gender == GenderEnum.Other)"
    name="Gender" @onchange="@(() => User.Gender = GenderEnum.Other)" />
<label>Other</label>
```

We can also have a function called from `@onchange` like
`@onchange="@UpdateGender"`

Comment: If you're doing this, might as well make a generic component that accepts any Enum type and loops through its values.

Comment: Sure that can be done! But the question is about binding simple radio buttons. I have chosen a simple Gender enum example. While choosing the gender example itself, I was not sure to go ahead since it might start a gender identity war in the comments as I left many genders in my example.

Comment: I like this, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Of course it is, [it is described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-and-input-components#radio-buttons):

```
@using System.Globalization
@typeparam TValue
@inherits InputBase<TValue>

<input @attributes="AdditionalAttributes" type="radio" value="@SelectedValue" 
       checked="@(SelectedValue.Equals(Value))" @onchange="OnChange" />

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public TValue SelectedValue { get; set; }

    private void OnChange(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        CurrentValueAsString = args.Value.ToString();
    }

    protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string value, 
        out TValue result, out string errorMessage)
    {
        var success = BindConverter.TryConvertTo<TValue>(
            value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out var parsedValue);
        if (success)
        {
            result = parsedValue;
            errorMessage = null;

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            result = default;
            errorMessage = $"{FieldIdentifier.FieldName} field isn't valid.";

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
@page "/RadioButtonExample"
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

<h1>Radio Button Group Test</h1>

<EditForm Model="@model" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />

    @for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        <label>
           <InputRadio name="rate" SelectedValue="i" @bind-Value="model.Rating" />
           @i
        </label>
    }

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>

<p>You chose: @model.Rating</p>

@code {
    private Model model = new Model();

    private void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        ...
    }

    public class Model
    {
        [Range(1, 5)]
        public int Rating { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#radio-buttons

Comment: Sure, but how do you do that without using the MS InputRadio inside an EditForm? <input type="text"... can @bind without any problems. How to do that with <input type="radio"...?

Comment: Unsure whats changed since 2020, but this InputGroup solution taken as is shown above gives stacktrace error of:
InvalidOperationException: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.InputRadio`1[System.String] must have an ancestor Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.InputRadioGroup`1[System.String] with a matching 'Name' property, if specified.

Comment: I mean. . . the error message literally says how to solve the error.